# Does XMLRead.Create(new StringReader) provide capability to read non-unicode (BIG5)?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, unicode, big5

I am trying to access a webpage that has BIG5 encoding paragraph. After retrieving the xml data, I use XMLRead.Create(new StringReader(xmldata)) and get the big5 characters from reader.Value of XmlNodeType.Text type. In WP runtime, it does not support BIG5 encoding so I have to get each byte and convert to unicode for display on WP7. However, the byte I get the from reader.Value seems not what I expected. For example, the first Chinese character is B5E1. But I got FDFD. What's wrong is that?

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmldata)))  
while (reader.Read())  
    switch (reader.NodeType)  
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            string s = reader.Value;  
            foreach (byte input in s)  
                # the input gives unexpected result
```

The webpage to load is http://feeds.feedburner.com/nownews/politic

I am using VS2010 for WP7 development work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since big5 is a double byte character set you'll need two bytes at a time in order to get the correct character. Based on your example it looks like you are only reading one byte.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to get 1st byte to see if the leading byte is in range or not. But the value is not B5 or E1.

Comment: I am guess that "String s = reader.Value;", s has already been modified. So the bytes I read out are wrong. If characters are ASCII code in the string, it displayed ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone SDK doesn't support BIG5 encoding, but if you need it, just go ahead and generate the encoding class with the [Silverlight Encoding Generator](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator).

Comment: Nice link but unfortunately it seems that the tool doesn't support double byte character sets thus it cannot create a big5 encoding class.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have tried the tool and got same issue that it does not support 2bytes encoding.

Answer (score 1):

An encoding defines how a byte stream is translated into a .Net string. Since you cannot apply the BIG5 encoding, .Net will choose either a default encoding or the one given in the XML file.

The result is that as you parse the XmlReader, the translation bytes=>string has already taken place, and the foreach(byte in string) iterates over the .Net representation of the wrongly translated string.

I have not worked with these parts of the API, but it seems that the [XmlReader methods mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.canreadbinarycontent.aspx) are the ones to retrieve the original byte stream behind an XML node.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The method you mentioned (CanReadBinaryContent) does not supported in WP package. Tried to add the reference for that system.xml.dll but got error.